# Building cascade structure

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I just want to build a cascade structure like `Category-Subject-Post` in my project. 
Here is my code:

> models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    slug_category = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("skill:subjects", kwargs={"slug_category": self.slug_category})

class Subject(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug_subject = models.SlugField(unique=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("skill:subject", kwargs={
        "slug_category": self.category.slug_category,
        "slug_subject": self.slug_subject
    })


class Post(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    ...
```

> views.py:

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'category_it': Category.objects.filter(class_name='IT'),
        'category_ps': Category.objects.filter(class_name='PS'),
        'category_ac': Category.objects.filter(class_name='AC'),
        'category_tc': Category.objects.filter(class_name='TC'),
        'category_sc': Category.objects.filter(class_name='SC'),
        'category_ss': Category.objects.filter(class_name='SS'),
    }
    return render(request, 'skill/index.html', context)

class SubjectsView(generic.ListView):
    model = Subject
    queryset = Subject.objects.all()
    template_name = "skill/subjects.html"


class SubjectView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    template_name = 'skill/subject.html'
```

> urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # /programming
    url(r'^(?P<slug_category>[\w-]+)/$', views.SubjectsView.as_view(), name='subjects'),
    # /programming/git
    url(r'^(?P<slug_category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug_subject>[\w-]+)/$', views.SubjectView.as_view(), name='subject'),
    # /programming/git/43121
    url(r'^(?P<slug_category>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug_subject>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),
]
```

templates:

> index.html:

```
{% for category in category_it %}
    <a href="{% url 'skill:subjects' category.slug_category %}" class="item">{{ category }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

> subjects.html:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}" class="item"><h4>{{ object }}</h4></a>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't know what query I need for that and where(views or template), I tried and hardcoded it (index in views.py and template but 6times larger) but can't afford it on the next step because of the scope.

I need *categories* in **index.html**, *list of subjects* belonging to particular category in **subjects.html** and *posts belonging to their subject* in **subject.html**. Can you please help me with finding the working solution

Comment: Wait 5 min. I write answer.

Answer (score 1):

This site is invaluable to work your way around [Class Based Views (ListView)](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.list/ListView/)

I think you need to override the `get` method, something like this:

```
class SubjectsView(generic.ListView):
    ... 
    def get(self, request, *args, slug_category=None, **kwargs):
        if slug_category:
            self.queryset = Subject.objects.filter(category__slug_category=slug_category)
        super(SubjectsView, self).get(request, *args, slug_category=slug_category, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset = Subject.objects.get(category=parametrocategoria)
queryset = Post.objects.get(subject=parametrosubjet)
```

You simply choose to perform query